# Block network access of a process using eBPF?

Tags: networking, ebpf

I know XDP can be used to drop packets/control network, but how we can achieve similar thing at process level?

The kernel has no idea what process we are running, so how can I block network access of a particular process using eBPF (something like [Opensnitch](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSnitch does not block packets with eBPF.

It does use eBPF, but for tracing the packets at different points in the kernel stack, and to collect metrics and metadata about those packets, including information about the process to which the related flow is attached. You can have a look at [the related probes in OpenSnitch's directory](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/blob/master/ebpf_prog/opensnitch.c).

Then this information is passed to user space via eBPF maps, and the user space agent inserts new rules with `iptables` or `nftables` to block the packets. (It could use XDP programs instead for blocking, but you still need a separation between the tracing programs that collect the data and whatever is used in the network stack to block packets.)

If you want to set up something system-wide to drop packets related to a specific process, you probably want to go for a similar approach: setting up a tracing part to identify to which process the connection is related, and then feeding this information to another component to drop the packets.

If, instead, you have already identified a specific process that you want to monitor, and for which you want to filter packets (allowing some, but not all packets), then you can maybe use some of the other eBPF hooks (sockets or cgroup-related) to attach a program to the specific socket or network stack function.